# Equetion of difference sinus and cosinus functions

Tags: trigonometry

Hi i have question i have something like this:

$2 \sin 5t - 5 \cos 5t = A \sin(5t + \varphi)$

The main question is :

Is there any formulas or something to change left side of "$=$" to look similar to right?

The main goal is to make left side similar to right not to solve equation

$A = \frac{e^{2x}}{29}\cdot e^{-2x} = \frac{1}{29}$

Comment: Hint:

$$\sin(a+b) = \sin(a) \cos(b) + \sin(b) \cos(a)$$

To make both sides equal you will need to figure out what $A$ is.

Comment: I tryied it before i wrote this question. I used all my ideas and got nothing.

Comment: I added $A$ my mistake.

Comment: Expand the right hand side using what I did. Replace $A$ with the value you gave. Note also that your equation has no solutions for the value of $A$ given.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P$ be the point $(2, -5)$ with length $ r = \sqrt{2^2 + (-5)^2} = \sqrt{29}$ and angle $\varphi$. Then

$\cos \varphi= \dfrac xr = \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{29}}$

$\sin \varphi= \dfrac yr = \dfrac{-5}{\sqrt{29}}$

Then
\begin{align}
  2 \sin 5t - 5 \cos 5t
  &= \sqrt{29}
     \left(
       \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{29}} \sin 5t
       +
       \dfrac{-5}{\sqrt{29}} \cos 5t \right)\\
  &= \sqrt{29}
     (\cos \varphi \sin 5t
     + \sin \varphi \cos 5t)\\
  &= \sqrt{29} \sin(5t + \varphi)
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Hint: multiply by $\sqrt{29}$ on LHS and also divide by it, giving $$\sqrt{29}(\frac{2}{\sqrt{29}}\sin{5t}-\frac{5}{\sqrt{29}}\cos{5t})$$ which can be written as $$\sqrt{29}\sin({5t+\alpha})$$ where $\alpha$ is $tan^{-1}\frac{-5}{2}$

Comment: o.O Thats amazing, if you can explain how you change expression in brackets to sin and arctg i would be very grateful

Comment: Hmm what if $A$ on the left and right aren't the same? 
$\sqrt{29} \sin(5t + (- \alpha)) = \frac{1}{29} \sin(5t + \beta)$

Comment: Here $\alpha$ is an angle such that $\cos\alpha=\frac{2}{\sqrt{29}}$ and $\sin\alpha=\frac{5}{\sqrt{29}}$ and then look at sin(x+y)=sinxcosy+coxsiny, and then, compare the terms.

Comment: Yes but still $A$ on the left and $A$ on the right are not equal. Why?  Both left and right side should be diffrence in angle $\alpha$ and $\beta$

Comment: $\sqrt{29} (\cos( \arccos(\frac{2}{\sqrt{29}})) \sin 5t - sin( \arcsin(\frac{5}{\sqrt{29}})) \cos 5t)$ This isn't equal to this equation? How can i transform it to get $tan^{-1} \frac{-5}{2}$